# how to define two delegates in the @interface line

Tags: ios, delegates, uiscrollview

In iOS,I would like to include both a delegate for the flipsideView (from a Utility Application template) and a delegate to allow to scroll the view.
My attempt, which does not work, is:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController 
<FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
 }
```

I tried to place a comma (,) or a space between the two <>, but it does not work. 
Would someone be able and willing to help me concerning this question?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController 
  <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> 
{

}
```

The syntax is as follows:

> @interface ClassName : ItsSuperclass <
>   protocol list >

For example for multiple protocols:

> @interface Formatter : NSObject <
>   Formatting, Prettifying >

You can read more on protocols and how to [adopt and conform in Apple's official Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW3).

Answer (score 5):

Only one `<>` is required with comma separating the protocols.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController 
<FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the advice Krishnan, I am just learning how stackoverflow functions, and really enjoy it.